# Proving that $\Bbb{Q}(\xi^2 2^{2/5}+\xi^3 2^{3/5})=\Bbb{Q}(\xi2^{1/5})$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $\xi$ be the the fifth root of unity $\ne 1$. Let $z=\xi2^{1/5}$ and $t=z^2+z^3$.

I would to prove that $\Bbb{Q}(t)=\Bbb{Q}(z)$. As $\Bbb{Q}(z)$ is the smallest field containing $z$ it contains $z^2$ and $z^3$ and so $z^3+z^2$.

However, the converse seems more 'difficult', is it possible to prove it without calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see is to compute the first powers of t:
$$t^2=z^4+2z^5+z^6=4+2z+z^4$$
and
$$t^3=z^6+3z^7+3z^8+z^9=z+6z^2+6z^3+z^4=z+z^4+6t.$$
Now it is clear that
$$t^2-t^3+6t-4=z,$$
hence the converse inclusion follows immediately. But if you meant exactly this by *calculus*, then I don't know any direct result (and actually don't expect any, as extensions of this type can vary a lot by a simple change of constants).

Comment: I tried like you, but as always I made a miscalculation, I'm terrible. Thanks +1

Comment: I've probably edited my question $4$ times due to miscalculations :P You are welcome